# Firefox converts URI to URL: How to force it to display URI

Tags: javascript, url, browser, uri

I want to generate an URL in which the whitespace is encoded to "%20", but the Browser automatically converts "%20" to whitespace. It's just a problem with Firefox and "%20"/whitespace. The comma "%2C"/, is not converted...

Is it possible to force firefox to show the URI and not converted URL?

The URL in the Browser should look like this (with %20 instead of whitespace)

[image]

But Browser automatically converts it to this (with whitespace)

[image]

Comment: every browser or just a specific one ?

Comment: As far as I can see it's just a problem with firefox

Comment: Use `+` instead

Comment: What is your practical problem with this? If you're copying the URL to the clipboard, a correct URL encoded address is copied.

Comment: @Teemu It's annoying that what I'm seeing is not what I'm copying, nor what is actually there. Creates mental discrepancies and frustrations.

Answer (score 0):

have a try with the second part of this code

```js
const urlString = `https://www.sample.com/events?area=frankfurt am main`

let url = new URL(urlString);
console.log(url.toString()); // your %20

url = new URL(urlString.replace(/ /g,"+"));
console.log(url.toString()); // + instead of %20
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```js
console.log(encodeURI('domain.com?q=something text'));
```

Comment: That does just the same. Firefox will show the space